# SQL: Extract last 5 digits in a string after special char

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to extract last 5 digits in title(free text field) after special char ': ' (with a space). Sample records are as follows:

```
    title column
  1  ABC Requirement1 - 1,500 - 3,000 sq m : 12345
  2  10,000 sft shed requirement
  3  OFFICES REQUIRED 500/700 SQ FT : 56789
  4  Land Acquisition : 34567
  5  Storage Requirement : 12345
  6  Land Requirement :100 sq.m
```

my result set should be as follows:

```
   ID
1 12345
3 56789
4 34567
5 12345
```

It should only pick up last 5 digits(ID) after special char ': ' and ignore other records with ': ' in between. I am trying to extract ID values to join with another table. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the query that you want.

```
SELECT  LEFT(SUBSTRING(Title, CHARINDEX(': ', Title) + 2, LEN(Title)), 5)
FROM    @table
WHERE   [Title] LIKE '%: %'
AND ISNUMERIC(LEFT(SUBSTRING(Title, CHARINDEX(': ', Title) + 2, LEN(Title)), 5)) = 1
```

Comment: This answer doesn't check to make sure that the last 5 characters of [Title] are numeric, which the OP requires.

Comment: My bad. I only did what was shown in the result. Please refer to @StanShaw 's answer for a complete solution. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the referral - lol.  I added the additional line of the `WHERE` clause to your answer since it was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT Id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(':', Title, 1) > 1
                THEN SUBSTRING(Title, CHARINDEX(':', Title, 1) + 2, 5)
            END AS TitleID
    FROM RequirementTable
    )
SELECT ID
    ,TitleID
FROM CTE
WHERE ISNUMERIC(TitleID) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should seriously reconsider the way you're storing your data if you need to go to these lengths to form a relation between records.  This is potentially disastrous should your data ever include ': ' naturally and without ending in a foreign key value.  And you most likely won't figure that out until it's too late and processing and/or other applications fail as a result.

However, to answer the question as it was asked, I have the same thing as @ChesterLin, but with sample data and including the 'ID' column in the output.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (ID int, Title varchar(255))

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES
(1, 'ABC Requirement1 - 1,500 - 3,000 sq m : 12345'),
(2, '10,000 sft shed requirement'),
(3, 'OFFICES REQUIRED 500/700 SQ FT : 56789'),
(4, 'Land Acquisition : 34567'),
(5, 'Storage Requirement : 12345'),
(6, 'Land Requirement :100 sq.m')


SELECT  ID, LEFT(SUBSTRING(Title, CHARINDEX(': ', Title) + 2, LEN(Title)), 5) AS [Extracted Value]
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   [Title] LIKE '%: %'
AND ISNUMERIC(LEFT(SUBSTRING(Title, CHARINDEX(': ', Title) + 2, LEN(Title)), 5)) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get last 5 digits

```
SUBSTR(column, LENGTH(column) - 5, 5)
```

OR

```
SELECT RIGHT('ABC Requirement1 - 1,500 - 3,000 sq m : 12345',5)
```

OR Full query

```
SELECT substr(title, character(title)-5) from table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
substr(column, -5, 5)
```

Starts from the last character in the string, and gives the five characters. 
Then cast it as INT.

```
select cast(substr(column, -5, 5) as INT) as ID from table_name
where isnumeric(substr(column, -5, 5)) = 1
```

I hope this will work. Or, something like this.

Comment: This query will throw an error because it isn't filtering the records per the OP's requirements.

Comment: would this not give him the results now? as per the OP, "It should only pick up last 5 digits(ID) after special char **': '** and ignore other records with **': '** in between."  both the special char specifications are same. So, it will have to process through all the lines!

Comment: No, it still would cause errors if the end of the [Title] column contained numeric values - even if they lacked the required ': '.  You need to check for the presence of both.  Check my or ChesterLin's answer and compare.

Comment: But the OP hasn't stated anything about that. What if there are no lines in his column without ": ". That part of the query becomes redundant.

Comment: The OP did state that.  I also see you edited your post to include it, so it's ironic that you're arguing?

Comment: I'm just saying, it is pointless to keep that filter. he stated that if the last five characters are numeric, it should write the characters, and not what the filter states. "It should only pick up last 5 digits(ID) after special char ': ' and ignore other records with ': ' in between."

Comment: If it was pointless, why did you edit your answer to include it?  The fact is that it would be possible for data to include ': ' and NOT end in numeric values - which means you should exclude them - similarly, it would be possible for data to end in numeric values and NOT include ': '.  That is why you need to check for both - and that is why it is not pointless.

Comment: Hey @stanshaw, why are you so fixated on what I did. I was just trying to figure out what your thought was behind this query. You thought the bigger picture. I was going with what the OP provided. Peace!

Comment: Lol - I'm not "fixated".  That's how this site works.  You post an answer and other people give feedback on why it's good or bad.  If you want to post answers without considering the bigger picture, that's your prerogative - but for the sake of future users, someone needs to point out your mistakes so that they're not repeated.  Learn how to take some criticism on this site and you will grow.

Comment: LOL - thanks! You could have stated all the facts in your first comment though. That'd have stopped my curiosity grow then and there. That's effective criticism. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yep, it's my fault that you didn't read and understand the question before posting an incorrect answer.  Sorry about that.